# Maintaining Two Different Source Control Servers

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019, tfvc

We have been hired by a client who would like us to check in code to their Azure Devops Team Foundation Version Control server.

We have our own small team of developers that will work on this project and commit changes to our own TFVC server first. Once all check-ins are approved, we would then like to commit all of our changes to our client's TFVC server.  We have been given a single login to their TFS system, so we would like to check in our code into their system using the single login that was provided to us. The client does not need to know the history of all of our own developer's work, we would like them to see our check in as a single author. We don't want to migrate, as this will be a common task for us.

What's the most straightforward way we could do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not  possible to sync code on 2 different TFS server. Since you work in one workspace (command line and GUI) at a time. And a workspace cannot span servers.

The only workaround here is manually copy/past your code directly through windows file system. Finally check in code to your client's TFVC server.

The better solution is to convince your clients to use Git repositories instead of TFVC. There is a lot to win here! And you could migrate your sources with **[git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs)** with all history.